# How do I add pure javascript files into Angular 4 component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to use an external javascript library in an angular 4 component but I am having trouble using it.
The library I want to install is the plaid link library and I have downloaded the .js file and added it to the assets folder and included it into `angular-cli.json` scripts location.

The object imported from the class is giving me the error `Plaid is not defined`. How can I successfully include the pure javascript file into angular typescript?

This is the file I would like to include:

https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js

Thanks

Comment: *The class from the file is not showing up in my component.* What does that mean?

Comment: I am gettting the error when I run the constructor: `Plaid is not defined`.

Comment: I see. Does the library come with a type definition (*.d.ts) file? I think that is all you are missing. [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib) is a link to the steps you follow to add a 3rd party library to a ng4 project. The `npm install @types...` step might be what you are missing.

Comment: There aren't any types because the library is meant to be run in pure javascript.

Comment: What about adding a simple script tag in your index.html?

Comment: I need a button that fires a method from the script when it is pressed. If it is in the index.html I am unable to fire the method from the correct component.

Comment: With a script ta in index.html, is the error firing just in the compiler? or once the app is running in the browser?

Comment: Once the app is running in the browser

Comment: Everything works fine in index.html it’s just when running from another components html that there is a problem. Best case scenario I can somehow run it from typescript In the component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your library has a Plaid object, which is not known to the TypeScript compiler.Create a file src/typings.d.ts with the following content:

```
declare var Plaid: any;
```

Or you can declare this variable inside your component:

```
var Plaid: any;
```